# sql query with for loop and array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a for loop that i use to perform a syntax multiple times:

```
for ($c=1; $c<=$rowCount; $c++){
    $reas[$c-1]=$_SESSION["reas".$c];
    $exp[$c-1]=$conn->query("SELECT reason_exp from rehab_reasons where reason_name='".$reas[$c-1]."'");

}
```

now i want to echo it using for loop too..

```
for ($x=0; $x<$rowCount; $x++){
$text=$act[$x].' was given to '.$conj[$x].' '.$reas[$x].' '.$exp[$x]['reason_exp'];
}
```

it seems not working.. wht i want to do is to have:
$exp[0]= reason_exp from the database where reason_name= $reas[0]
$exp[1]= reason_exp from the database where reason_name= $reas[1]
...
and so on..

what is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$text=$act[$x].' was given to '.$conj[$x].' '.$reas[$x].' '.($exp[$x]['reason_exp']);
```

Comment: still got this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array